# Is there a way to ferment mustard seeds for homemade mustard?

Tags: mustard

I have a recipe for mustard that calls for fermented mustard seeds - is there a way to ferment them at home?

Answer (score 1):

Whey appears to be an agent for lacto-fermenting mustard.  [This recipe](http://ediblearia.com/2009/03/10/lacto-fermented-organic-whole-grain-mustard/) for lacto-fermented mustard describes a process of combining ingredients and then letting them ferment after the recipe is put together by leaving out over a few days.

[This recipe](http://www.dvo.com/recipe_pages/india/Mustard_Seed_Raita.html) for a mustard seed raita uses yogurt as the fermentation ingredient, which means that you would have to use yogurt with active cultures.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [reasonably involved text behind the link on home fermentation](http://www.cheeseslave.com/2009/07/30/got-bacteria-10-reasons-to-eat-fermented-foods/). Not specific enough an answer for you, sorry. My google-fu was not strong enough for this one. It may help you get started though.